# No bundles specified

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

Iam using OSGi frame work in eclipse(Equinox)for developing some application .Actually iam new to OSGi framework.while iam trying to run the program in eclipse using start commant (osgi> start)'No bundles speicified ' is showing.Message 'Framework is shutdown' is showing while checking whether the frame work is installed or not using the commant(osgi> ss) .I also include the jar file for Equinox(org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar).following is the code

```
package testosgi;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello java World!!");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Goodbye java World!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your activator is fine.  What matters is what launch config do you use?  OSGi?  What bundles do you include in that launch config?  Are you running with `-Dosgi.noShutdown=true`? Please update your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'm assuming you're creating the plug-in / bundle in Eclipse and testing it when "running as eclipse application". This opens a "runtime eclipse" where your workspace bundles (the ones you have installed in the main eclipse and the ones you create on your own in your workspace) are enabled.

The start command should receive an argument with a bundle name like

```
start my-bundle
```

This is why you're getting a "No bundle(s) specified!".
An easier view is the "Plug-in Registry" view in Eclipse (alt+shift+q, q -> type plug-in -> choose plug-in registry)
Find your bundle in long list (there's a filter box).

1. Is there a green "play" icon on the plug-in icon?
   If there is, check your console the "Hello World!" should have already been printed out.
2. There isn't an arrow?
   Right click the icon and choose "Show Advanced Oprations". Right click again and choose "start". That should run your activator.

Basically Eclipse is not running your plugin's activator until it is actually required by some other package. When there is a UI contribution in a plug-in, then one of its classes are required and the activator runs, when there isn't you have to either manually run it, or try to use it from some other bundle.

Just to make sure, open your plugin.xml and go to the Overview tab.
Make sure "Activate this plugin when one of its classes are loaded" is checked.